# Import XML file into SQL server database

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, import

How do I import an XML file into a SQL Server Database using C# and .NET in a windows application?

The table name and column names of the SQL Server have to be automatically created (I saw somewhere that they were mapping explicitly every column of the XML table to the already created SQL table's columns).

Appreciate your help.

Sam.

Comment: It would depend on your XML file structure. Is it a simple one or complex one ? Depending on the complexity you might need to add code for mapping.

Comment: Can you **show us** one of your XML files and explain in more detail **how** this needs to be imported?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of think this is two questions. So it kind of gets two answers.

1) You would need to parse out the name of the nodes to create column names.  Depending on how "deep" your XML is, it may need multiple tables.  You'd then connect to your database and run sql statements through code (`SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects) to create the tables with the appropriate columns. (`CREATE TABLE Blah COLUMNS Bleh`, for instance).  There is also a SQL Specific API (I think) the name of which I can't recall that will let you do that in a slightly more object-oriented way.  The gist is the same: marshal your table and column names, create your table(s) with the appropriate columns.

2) You then have a couple of options- the best would probably be to marshal DataSets from the XML (plenty of examples exist) and then use XML Bulk Insert to upload the whole kit-and-caboodle to SQL all at once.

Let me just say, though, that this is a really ugly solution.  SSIS would probably be able to do the same thing for more easily if that's an option.